# Cannot connect via local port after closing connection

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, hole-punching

I am trying to prototype TCP hole punching of a NAT as described in this paper http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/.

I have this simple piece of code that tries to open a connection to a server on a specific local port. I am trying to observe on the public server if the NAT maps both the connections to the same NAT mapping.

```
int localPort = getFreeLocalPort();

     while (true) {

        Socket connection = new Socket(_publicServerHost,_publicServerPort,
                 getLocalSocketAddress(), localPort);

        connection.setReuseAddress(true);

        connection.close();

     }
```

The 1st time it connects fine. But the 2nd attempt it throws an exception:

Local port chosen for hole punching: 65416

2012-06-17 15:55:21,545 ERROR - Address already in use: connect

2012-06-17 15:55:25,175 DEBUG - Details: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:375) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:249) ~[na:1.6.0_24]

Answer (score 1):

try adding `connection.setSoLinger(true, 0);` directly before connection.close();.

Like so:

```
connection.setSoLinger(true, 0);
connection.close();
```

This forces the OS to release the socket.

Comment: And discard any pending send data ... Not recommended.

Comment: if(connection.isConnected() && connection.isBound()) {
                connection.setSoLinger(true, 0);
                connection.close();
            }
But I get a java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed exception

Comment: @pkrish `Socket.isConnected()` only tells you whether you have connected the socket. `Socket.isBound()` only tells you whether you have bound the socket. Neither tells you whether you have closed the socket, nor for that matter when the peer has done so. In any case you are barking completely up the wrong tree with all this. See my answer.

Comment: @dantuch I tried the setSoLinger option on another machine in a different network, and it seems to work. Although I could go up to 10 connections, which is fine. I am using windows 7 in both machines, so I cannot understand the different behavior. May be the NAT behavior is different?

Answer (score 0):

On what basis was the local port chosen? Obviosuly not a sound one. You would be better off letting the system choose it, by specifying zero, and getting the actual value *from* the socket after opening, if you need it at all.

Comment: The getFreeLocalPort() method gets a free local port. ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(0); int port = server.getLocalPort();

Comment: @pkrish Err, but, obviously, it *doesn't* get a free local port, because it picks one that is still in TIME_WAIT. The technique I have described *will* get a free local port with 100% reliability.

Comment: I want to make multiple connections over the same local port. i.e, the port in TIME_WAIT state. connection.setReuseAddress(true); is supposed to let you do this. The reason for doing this is to achieve TCP hole punching. If you read the paper (section 4.1) that I have linked to, it explains it in more detail.

Comment: @pkrish setSoLinger() isn't 'meant to do' any such thing. It is just a way of resetting connections, among other things, which is a bad thing to do to a TCP connection, because you can lose data. What happened when you tried it my way?

Comment: By your method, I just get the same behavior since I would be reusing the port before the TIME_WAIT period. I think I should have the server close the connection as that would prevent the client socket from entering TIME_WAIT.

Comment: @pkrish By my method you cannot possibly get a port in TIME_WAIT state, and you cannot get a bind exception of any kind unless you have actually exhausted the port space completely. Clearly you still haven't tried it.

Comment: Don't think you are getting me. When I first get a local port by your method, I do get a free port and I can open a socket without issues. Now I close that connection and open a new connection via the "same" local port that I got earlier. This action throws an exception, since the port enters a TIME_WAIT state after the first connection was closed. If I put the thread to sleep for 2 min (for the port to come out of TIME_WAIT state) after closing the connection and try again it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem ?
setReuseAddress() should be called before port is assigned.

```
Socket connection = new Socket();
connection.setReuseAddress(true);
connection.bind( ...);
```